# Most number of save proficiencies (without being a Monk)?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, multi-classing, unearthed-arcana

Besides a 14th level Monk, what is the most amount of saving throws a character can be proficient in permanently?

As best I can tell, it's only possible to gain proficiency in 4 saves by playing a Rogue to 15th level and picking up the Resilient feat along the way. Doing this gives the character proficiency in Dex, Int, Wis, and whichever save Resilient is applied to.

Is this the best that can be achieved? Is it possible to be proficient in 5 or even all 6 saves without being a monk? I'm interested in anything that can be achieved using the the standard rules or UA material.

Comment: I wish you'd remove the answer in the question ruling out monks because you've already thought of it and placed it an actual answer so I can upvote it and you could accept it if no better answer comes.

Answer (score 3):

## At the time of the OP

Even before Xanathar's Guide to Everything, you could get 5 saves by having your rogue acquire a Transmuter's Stone with the Constitution save benefit from a School of Transmutation Wizard (PH 119).

A human (variant) wizard could actually get all 6 saves at level 1 with a Shapechange scroll (albeit temporarily). Intelligence from the Wizard class proficiencies, Strength from the Resilient feat, and the other 4 from one of the Dragon Wyrmlings (MM 106).

---

## Now

With the new Xanathar's Guide subclasses, a character can acquire all 6 saves by himself without any form changes. These are the necessary classes in order:

**1. Ranger (Gloom Stalker) 7**

This provides the Strength and Dexterity saves from Ranger, Charisma saves from Resilient (taken at 4), and Wisdom saves from Iron Mind (XGtE 42).

**2. Fighter (Samurai) 7**

This multi-class gives Intelligence saves via the Elegant Courtier feature (XGtE 31)

**3. Wizard (School of Transmutation) 6**

Just like before, the Transmuter's Stone gives Constitution saves.

Answer (score 1):

I have to reiterate that feats are optional for other readers so check with your DM.

RAW, it would appear that using the Resilient feat you can only get up to 3 total proficiencies in saves (2 for class and 1 from the feat) unless as you stated you are a Rogue then 4 is possible with the Slippery Mind feature. As you can only take any feat only once unless its description says otherwise. Only Elemental Adept can be taken more than once with PHB raw and that was confirmed as not an oversight by [Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/07/the-only-feat-that-you-can-take-more-than-once/).

Looking through the base magical items in the DMG none of them seem to grant saving through proficiencies.

Short of a kind DM and a wish spell I don't see a way to get more. It would seem to me that proficiency in a save for a single target would be less powerful than granting 10 creatures resistance permanently to a single damage type, then of course there is the potential risk to the caster of the wish and all that fun that is covered in other questions.

Upon further digging it appears that not even the listed divine blessings nor the epic boons from the DMG would grant additional proficiency, only advantage on rolls for them.

Only the Monk seems to have the ability to become proficient with Death Saves though due to the wording of the class feature.

Comment: Bear in mind that the 4th save proficiency per my question stems from the Rogue class feature Slippery Mind, which grants Wisdom saving throw proficiency.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Yup, I had already edited to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: For whatever it is worth, D&D Beyond considers "Resilient (Constitution)" and "Resilient (Strength)" and etc. to be distinct feats and lets you take more than one (but of course not the same one twice).

Comment: @mattdm being a developer myself and that being in beta I would have to write that off as a bug until it goes to final release or someone addresses it officially.

Comment: @Slagmoth Doesn't mean it isn't a bug, but as far as I know D&D Beyond isn't beta at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't exactly the same; it's pretty equivalent, in that having advantage on a save is about as good (or better at lower levels) than having proficiency: Be a 2nd level (or more) gnomish barbarian.  You will almost always have either proficiency or advantage on saves.  Barbarian gets you proficiency in Str and Con.  2nd level Barbarian gets you advantage on Dex, for any save you can see, which is most of them.  Gnome gets you advantage on Int, Wis, and Chr for saves vs. magic, which again is most of them.  Combined with good hit points, and raging damage resistance, it's a toughness package that's hard to beat.  Go for the Bear at 3rd level for all damage resistance (when raging), and you'll pretty much always be the last man standing.